# fork() more diagnostic from the exit status of child process

Tags: c, fork

Is there a way to get more diganostic information when child process created using fork get failed with some exit status. Below is a sample code to list out the problem (comments where we are looking to get more information).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int exitstatus = 0;
    int bSuccess = 1;
    char argv[2][20] = { {0 , 0} };
    if(pid == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to create Forked process\n");
        bSuccess = 0;
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        // code for child
        if(-1 == execlp("perl", "perl", "/home/test/test.pl", "-b", "/opt/test/test", "-c", "64", "-t", "Imm", "-v", "a.b.c.d", argv[0], argv[1], (char*)0))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int retCode = waitpid(pid, &exitstatus, WUNTRACED);
        if(retCode != pid)
        {
            printf("Child process is not running\n");
            bSuccess = 0;
        }
        else if (WIFEXITED(exitstatus))
        {
            int statusCode = WEXITSTATUS(exitstatus);
            if (statusCode != 0)
            {
                // How to get more information what the status code means. Is there a way
                // to get more information?
                printf("Test.pl execution failed with exit status <%d>\n", statusCode);
                bSuccess = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(exitstatus))
        {
            // How to get more information what the status code means. Is there a way
            // to get more information?
            printf("Test.pl terminated due to uncaught signal <%d>\n", WTERMSIG(exitstatus));
            bSuccess = 0;
        }
        else if (WCOREDUMP(exitstatus))
        {
            printf("Test.pl terminated and process is crashed\n");
            bSuccess = 0;
        }
        else if (WIFSTOPPED(exitstatus))
        {
            // How to get more information what the status code means. Is there a way
            // to get more information?
            printf("Test.pl has stopped due to signal <%d>\n", WIFSTOPPED(exitstatus));
            bSuccess = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Success %d\n", bSuccess);
}
```

Now when the child process exit with an exit code we want to get more information. Like below is sample out when the child fails

> Test.pl execution failed with exit status <13>

Now I am unable to understand what this status code 13 means as the man pages also doen't list such error code. So I am looking to get more information why the execution of Test.pl fails from the C program. As when we run the script with same arguments from the shell it runs without any error.

So any thoughts how to caputre more information for the failure of the execution.

Comment: The exit code can be set arbitrarily by the exiting program (i.e. the value of the parameter to the `exit()`-call), hence the semantic of this value is completely dependent on the exiting program. _Most_ programs follow the convention, that 0 means "success" and anything else that some error occurred, but what exactly the value means should be documented somewhere (worst case in the source of your Test.pl)

Comment: If you take a look at `man waitpid`page every `exitstatus` has a description of what it means and using this status you can understand what you have to do. If you want to know more info you've to code it by yourself.